# Determining Conditional independence of events

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Your colleagues in a lab have sequenced DNA from a large population in order
to understand how a gene (G) influences two particular traits (T1 and T2). They find that
P(G) = 0.6, P(T1 | G) = 0.7, and P(T2 | G) = 0.9. They also observe that if a subject does
not have the gene G, they express neither T1 nor T2. The probability of a patient having both
T1 and T2 given that they have the gene G is 0.63.

a. Are T1 and T2 conditionally independent given G?

b. Are T1 and T2 conditionally independent given G^C?

c. Are T1 and T2 independent?

How do you find independence / conditional independence of an event?

Answer (score 1):

To say events $A$ and $B$ are independent given $C$, means that $A|C$ and $B|C$ are independent, which leads to $$P\Big([A|C]\cap [B|C]\Big)=P(A\cap B|C)=P(A|C)P(B|C)$$So, for example in the first case, try to show that $$P(T_1\cap T_2|G)=P(T_1|G)P(T_2|G)$$